# Install node.js on OS X 10.11

Tags: node.js, macos, homebrew

I have updated to El Captain. I am trying to install Node.js with homebrew and have an error:

```
==> ./configure --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/node/0.12.7 --without-npm --without-ssl2 --without-ssl3
==> make install
ld: library not found for -lgcc_s.10.5
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I have a set of questions:

- Is this problem specific to El Captain?
- Is this problem related with different versions of system libraries?
- Will the problem disappeared after some time, when the Formula will be update?
- Can I fix the formula by myself to install Node.js right now?

Comment: Any reason why you don't use the official Node.js installer instead?

Comment: It is more easy and convenient to install and update all software using one command (brew, in my case)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Installing XCode 7 beta solved the  problem.

Comment: Solved, or caused? On Yosemite, installing it is the catalyst for this issue. I had to download the 6.4 CLI tools and re-install them.

Comment: Solved.  But I have said about El Captain.